# Getting Postal Code using CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to get the postal code when my map region has changed by using CLGeocoder:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:13.184098 longitude:77.725978];

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
CLLocation *location=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:13.184098 longitude:77.725978];
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!(error))
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);

         NSString *Zipcode = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.postalCode];
         NSLog(@"%@",Zipcode);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error); // Error handling must required
     }
 }];
}
```

i am getting response like this

```
{ Country = India; CountryCode = IN; FormattedAddressLines = ( Amarwara, "Madhya Pradesh", India ); Name = Amarwara; State = "Madhya Pradesh"; SubAdministrativeArea = Chhindwara; SubLocality = Amarwara; }
```

I'm able to get the postal code for the first time. When the region changes, I try to reverse geocode the postal code. I even tried setting the location explicitly (line 1) and it's still returning null postal code. Can any one help this strange bug?

Comment: Keep in mind this (from Apple documentation) : Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. (When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder returns an error object with the value kCLErrorNetwork to the associated completion handler.)

Comment: Thank for the response but every time it's showing the address correctly problem was only in postal code

Comment: can you give me any alternate instead of calling GLCOder in every region change

Comment: Handling the error first, in order to know your problem, in your code add else { NSLog(@"Error:%@ \n Error code:%ld",[error localizedDescription],error.code);}

Comment: Another thing is sometimes calling a methods in some methods in correlation delegate make the methods will be call several times.

Comment: There is and Google Api with this functionality. But I think it's better first know you real problem.

Comment: I updated My question I think we can't send request less then one mint right?

Comment: This methods: ( - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated) is probably the worst place to do this request. You can read Apple Doc about it: "This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times to report updates to the map position. Therefore, your implementation of this method should be as lightweight as possible to avoid affecting scrolling performance." If you want declare a static int i=0; and a NSLog(@"How many times this methods is call:%ld",i); i++;

Comment: It´s important to know the goal of your App, and how important is this request will be success. You might need use too this:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:21.1700
                                                    longitude:72.8300];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                   if (error) {
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return;
                   }

                   if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                   {
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                       NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                       placemark.addressDictionary;

                       NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
                       NSString *address = [addressDictionary
                                            objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                       NSString *city = [addressDictionary
                                         objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                       NSString *state = [addressDictionary
                                          objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                       NSString *zip = [addressDictionary 
                                        objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];


                       NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);
                   }

               }];
```

Comment: when use CLGeocoder i am getting {
    Country = India;
    CountryCode = IN;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        Amarwara,
        "Madhya Pradesh",
        India
    );
    Name = Amarwara;
    State = "Madhya Pradesh";
    SubAdministrativeArea = Chhindwara;
    SubLocality = Amarwara;
}

Comment: this link will help you                               `http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/22/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0-part-2/`